# Style html table with column gradient

Tags: html, css

How can I style html table to desired result show on the picture. The requirement is to make gradient dynamic, independent from number of rows. Looking for non javascript, crossbrowser css solution with minimum of hacks.

This project is built with Tailwindcss 2. So it would be nice to have styled with it. I've created a simple sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-heyrovsky-nhkg8 with layout.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>25,99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>25,99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>25,99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>25,99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>25,99</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Desired result]

Comment: question have to contain a code directly inthe question itself. Links might change ro get deleted. Also if the sandbox changes/issue is resolved, the question would hold no furtehr value to the SO community

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with background like below

```css
td {
  padding:10px
}
td:first-child {
  background:#fff; /* don't show the gradient for the first td */
}
/* add a extra layer to darken the gradient */
td:last-child {
  background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0) 
    bottom /calc(100% - 10px) calc(100% - 5px) no-repeat;
  color:#fff;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  padding-bottom:15px;
  background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0) 
    center /calc(100% - 10px) calc(100% - 10px) no-repeat;
}
table {
  background:linear-gradient(red,lightblue); /* apply your gradient to the table */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>25,99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>25,99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>25,99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>25,99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>25,99</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Clever trick with a `calc()` in the gradient to limit the size of the darkened area, nice :)

Comment: I like your idea with calc. Is it possible to make extra layer to darken as background color and not gradient?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I wonder, why you didnt chose background-clip: content-box solution? Is there any caveats with it over gradient?

Comment: @Molfar because I am using the padding to define the size so cliping to the content will clip a lot and will keep only the layer around text. You can use it if you define width/height and a small padding or you consider and extra div inside the table

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with - though I couldn't quickly figure out way to exclude the background image from the gaps between cells in the first column:

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 5px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(46,178,240,1) 0%, rgba(138,29,208,1) 100%);
}
table > tbody {
    /* Setting the background-image on the tbody may work as well, but won't be rendered in the gaps between cells. */
    /*background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(46,178,240,1) 0%, rgba(138,29,208,1) 100%);*/
}

tbody > tr > td {
    padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
    margin: 0.5em;
}
tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: white;
}
tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2 );
    text-shadow: 0px 6px 6px #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>25,99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>25,99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>25,99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>25,99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>25,99</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: a box-shadow can help hiding the gradient from item (ex: `box-shadow: -5px 0 0 5px #fff;`)

Answer (score 0):

Add to TD number class like

```
 <td class="number1'> 25.99 </td>
```

After i dont know if you can style this without css or bootstrap.
But i will give you the font, and a little bit from css

```
.number1{ 
position: relative; /* so you can move it all around */ 
text-align: /* where ever you want /*; 
font-family:'digital-clock-font';
src: url('put_the_location_to_your_font.ttf or .otf'); 
border-style: solid #COLOR'
```

Also, you cand add all TD numbers in one div and class it:

```
<div class="numbers"> 
<td id="one"> 25,99 <td> 
<td id="two"> 25,99 <td> 
/* and the rest */
```

I think there is no way to style your content only by html.

Second Also you cand add css into your HTML:

```
<!doctype> 
<html lang="en'>
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<title> Name Page </title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<style> 
/* HERE WRITE THE STYLE */ 
</style>
</body> 
</html>
```